# How to expain the output of multi class classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have a Sequential model for 4 inputs and 3 output:

```
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=4, init='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, init='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    # serialize model to JSON
    model_json = model.to_json()
    with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
        json_file.write(model_json)
    # serialize weights to HDF5
    model.save_weights("model.h5")
    print("Saved model to disk")
    return model
```

I use the code below to predict the class.

```
prediction = model.predict(np.array([[data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3]]]))
```

But prediction's return is `[[ 0.49986306  0.5005092   0.50012374]]`.

How to explain the prediction's value?

Does below's explain is right?

```
Class1 -- when single value > 0.5 -> 1 (sum of 3 number ==1 )

Class2 -- when single value > 0.5 -> 1 (sum of 3 number ==2 )

Class3 -- when single value > 0.5 -> 1 (sum of 3 number ==3 )
```

If the explanation is wrong how to explain prediction's value?

Comment: If it's a classifier then you need add `softmax` layer at the end of layers to see which class is predicted by the model.

Comment: I use it as a multilayer perceptrons. I use the textbook's code. That doesn't have softmax layer.

Comment: As @Arman has already mentioned, you are supposed to use `softmax`. `sigmoid` can only be used in the outer layer for binary classification.

Comment: It is weird actually , because I don't think last layer need `sigmoid` activation by the way be cause it is not binary classification

Comment: I use the example "http://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-class-classification-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library/"

Comment: Does it be anything wrong. How to use softmax layer for my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, Ben. Could you explain more detail about this.Thanks

Comment: why not simply do json.dump('model.json', model.to_json()) ?

Comment: softmax is not a layer, it is an activation :) see the explaination in the answer below

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, since you cite [this tutorial](http://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-class-classification-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library/), you should know that there is a mistake.

You want here to predict which is the type of an iris. The `sigmoid` activation will give you 3 outputs between 0 and 1. You are training them so that 2 will have to go towards 0 and one towards 1. The thing is that nothing prevents that output to be 1, 1, 1 and that shouldn't happen as you want to detect only one type of Iris for one flower.

This is where the 'softmax' activation is useful. It is simply normalizing the outputs so that the sum of the 3 outputs will be 1. 
When you want to detect only one class between multiple possibilities you should always use the `softmax`. You can then interpret the output `i` as being the probability that the flower belongs to class `i`.

Your outputs will look like:

```
[0.1, 0.2, 0.7] or [0.3, 0.4, 0.3]
```

To interpret this, the first example has the highest probability for class 3, so class 3 is predicted. The second example has the highest probability for class 2 so class 2 is predicted.

the line you will have to change in your model to do this is :

```
model.add(Dense(3, init='normal', activation='softmax'))
```

Is it clearer?